# Check if a table exists or not

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

When I click on a link, it opens up a page which will have either on the below tables.

```
page 1 : html/body/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[2]/div[3]/form/table[2]/tbody....

Page 2 : html/body/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[2]/div[3]/form/table/tbody.....
```

I want to find out which table is loaded and make a decision. If the first page is loaded, then it goes to the loop, where as if the second page is loaded, it doesn't go to the else loop.

```
if(driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath of page 1)).isDisplayed()){
    System.out.println("is present");
}else {
    System.out.println("not");
}
```

How do i handle this?

Comment: use `else if` something like `else if (driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath of page 2)).isDisplayed()) // do somethig`

Comment: I tried that also. but it's stuck at if condition itself and never proceeds further.

Comment: If you have Selenium IDE on your browser, you can easily test which element your xpath finds, by entering your xpath expression on the target row of an individual command and pressing find. You'll get a visual highlight of the element on your browser. Handy for debugging what is actually found by the expression in cases like these.

Comment: @Leo What do you mean by it's stuck and never proceed?

Comment: It throws the following exception  org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"html/body/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[2]/div[3]/form/table[2]"}

Comment: @Leo I think you will have to wait till the page or elements get completely loaded. If selenium unable to find elements then it will throw exception as `NoSuchElementException`. Read [--> Explicit and Implicit Waits](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp)

Answer (score 0):

You should consider what your test is trying to achieve. Why is it that you don't know which table is going to be present? You SHOULD know which table is supposed to be present and be able to act accordingly in your test (otherwise the test fails, right?).

I was going to suggest using try/catch blocks around finding the element, and then checking if it's displayed (this method will work), but the way your code stands right now, it looks as if finding the element is enough to know that the table is displayed, so the two step process is a bit convoluted.

You could do something as simple as this...

```
try
{
  driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath of page 1));
  System.out.println("Page 1 is present");
}
catch (NoSuchElementException nsee)
{
  System.out.println("Page 2 is present");
}
```

But I would REALLY recommend taking a look at the reason why you don't KNOW which table is being displayed, and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

`isDisplayed` will not help you, you can use `isElementPresent` for isDisplayed you will get error 'Element not found'

Refer
[org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20536850/org-openqa-selenium-nosuchelementexception-unable-to-locate-element/20537102#20537102)