# org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element

Tags: selenium

This code is working fine if saleIdValueIs is correct but same is not working when saleIdValueIs data is not correct. Then it's showing a error message "   org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element"

```
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//html/body/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/fieldset/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/input")).sendKeys(saleIdValueIs);
        search_transaction_bt.click();
        boolean saleIdVisible=driver.findElementByXPath("/html/body/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div").isDisplayed();
        String searchedSaleIdValue=saleIdValue.getText();
        System.out.println(saleIdVisible);
            if (saleIdVisible==true){
                    System.out.println("sale id  is  - "+saleIdValueIs+ "output is "+searchedSaleIdValue);
                    }       
                else{
                     System.out.println("error message is coming ");
                    boolean errorMessageDisplayTest= driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div")).isDisplayed();
                    System.out.println(errorMessageDisplayTest);
                    boolean errorMessageVisible= driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div")).isDisplayed();
                    System.out.println(errorMessageVisible);
                    driver.close();
                    }
```

Comment: Try to avoid such long xpaths,this might cause your test case to  fail more often...you can use id,classname,name,title or other attributes to reduce the length of xpath. Much better results can be obtained with [cssSelectors.](http://sauceio.com/index.php/2010/01/selenium-totw-css-selectors-in-selenium-demystified/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your getting that error because element

 `driver.findElementByXPath("/html/body/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div")`
is not displayed, 
So instead of using `isDisplayed`, please use `isElementPresent`. Below is code, let me in case of any queries

```
boolean saleIdVisible= isElementPresent(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div"), driver);
if(Present)
{
System.out.println("sale id  is  - "+saleIdValueIs+ "output is "+searchedSaleIdValue);
 else{
System.out.println("error message is coming ");
boolean errorMessageDisplayTest= driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div")).isDisplayed();
System.out.println(errorMessageDisplayTest);
boolean errorMessageVisible= driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div")).isDisplayed();
System.out.println(errorMessageVisible);
driver.close();
}


public static boolean isElementPresent(By by, WebDriver driver) 
    {
      boolean present;
      try
        {
          driver.findElement(by);
          present = true;
        }catch (NoSuchElementException e)
        {
          present = false;
         }
     return present;
    }
```

Comment: Isn't it too expensive in terms of performance to handle this by catching exception? Is it the only way to control this?

Comment: @FelipeCorrea I wouldn't know the answer to that, but there's an alternative by checking the count using FindElements which won't throw an exception: 

if( driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector(exportCssSelector)).Count() > 0) {//element exists}